# Naming Thread within Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

I tried to pass name parameter together with Lambda Expressions, but couldn't make it work. The way I solved it is like that:

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() ->{
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (URISyntaxException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    );
    t1.setName("Internet Browser");
    t1.start();
```

Is there way? i could write it within a single line

```
new Thread("nameHere",() ->{....}).start();
```

if not, why isn't it possible?

Comment: You mix up parameter order. Correct order is `Thread(Runnable, String)`, not `Thread(String, Runnable)`.

Comment: If you'd look at the [public API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) you'd see that you simply have the constructor parameters of `Thread` the wrong way around.

Comment: ok great thanks for comment guys, my bad i though i have tried Runnable, string too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you have the [`public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-) constructor. So you can invoke it with:

```
new Thread(() ->{....},"nameHere").start();
```

> **`public Thread(Runnable target, String name)`**
>
> Allocates a new `Thread` object. This constructor has the same effect as
>   [`Thread (null, target, name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.ThreadGroup-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-).
>
> Parameters:
>     `target` - the object whose `run`
>   method is invoked when this thread is started. If `null`, this thread's
>   `run` method is invoked.
>     `name` - the name of the
>   new thread

So the order is different (runnable before the name). But I guess that is just a detail?

Comment: Please don't advise using nulls. There is perfectly fine constructor without `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: somehow I've overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i made bad assumption about the order. I will definetly check that next time.